# Radius of Convergence of $\sum ^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{k^{2}x^{k}}{2^{k}}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> How can I determine the radius of convergence for the following
>   function? $$\sum ^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{k^{2}x^{k}}{2^{k}}$$

Do I use the ratio test, and set $a_{k}=\frac{k^{2}x^{k}}{2^{k}}$?

Comment: You should use the root test, for good measure.

Comment: Would you know how to find that of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 x^k$? If so, can you use that to find this one?

Comment: When i do the root test i get $\frac{x}{2}$ so is the ratio of convergence -2 < x < 2?

Comment: You need $\;|x|\;$ to apply tests used for non-negative series. By the way, your result is correct.

Comment: okay so i just need to remember is $|x|$ then it will just be $|x| < 2$

Comment: Yes...this is just what you have in the two answers posted so far.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio test works just fine.  If $a_k=\frac{k^2\,x^k}{2^k}$, then

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}&=\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2\,\frac x2\\\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $\lim_{k\to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|=\frac {|x|}2$

and we see that the radius of convergence is $2$.

Comment: I think in order to apply the ratio test the way you did you need $\;|x|\;$ there as this test is for non-negative series, only.

Comment: @joanpemo Joan, yes, correct.  I'm working from my not-so-smart phone.  I've edited accordingly.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt[k]{\frac{k^2}{2^k}}=\frac{\sqrt[k]{k^2}}2\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}\frac12<1$$

and now use Cauchy-Hadamard formula or any other.